# Maximum of a multivariable function with an unbounded constrain

Tags: multivariable-calculus

let $x, y, z > 0$, $x+y+z=1$ and $x>z$. Define the function $f(x,y,z)=\sqrt{(x+z)(x-z)z^2}+2yz$. Find the maximum of $f(x,y,z)$. I used lagrange multiplier and let $x+y+z=1$ as a constrain at first and actually get a set of answer. But then I realized that $x+y+z=1$ is not bounded so maybe lagrange multiplier is not avliable here. Should I use Hessian matrix instead?

I used python to approximate the result and I got $x=0.30940$ and $y=0.42265$, which is what I got using lagrange multiplier.

Comment: You could produce the exact values of  $x,y,z,f$. They are simple.

Comment: I don't see that you need all that here. According to you, there is only one variable to your function. Just make a substitution and differentiate, etc.

Comment: Can you explain that a little bit more Allawonder? I can see that one of the variable can be substituted but I don't know how to subsitute another.